# Check if an array contains part of a string and find the index number

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const myArr = [ "blue", "red", "orange", "green" ];
```

I was wondering how to check if an array contains part of a string and the index number of the matching string.

I’ve seen this online but the index number doesn’t show the position unless it’s the full name in the array.

```js
myArr.indexOf("oran")
```

Comment: OP, what's wrong with the answers ?

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if there's at least one element verifying your condition :

```
var hasSome = myArr.some(function(v){ return v.indexOf("oran")>=0 })
```

If you need the index, a reverse `for` loop is the simpler solution :

```
for (var i=myArr.length; i--;) {
     if (myArr[i].indexOf("oran")>=0) break;
}
```

After the loop, `i` is `-1` if no element matches, it's its index if one matches.

Note that in ES6 (the next version of JavaScript), you'll have the `find` and `findIndex` methods on arrays and the `includes` method on strings, which means you'll be able to do

```
var i = myArr.findIndex(v => v.includes("oran"));
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `v.indexOf("oran")>=0` as opposed to `v.indexOf("oran")> -1`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Not really. But I don't see why use `>-1`. To be honest I would probably have used ̀ `~v.indexOf("oran")` or `/oran/.test(v)` in my own code.

Comment: maybe dystroy has a fear of -. It is the same either way.

Comment: That's reasonable, I hadn't intended it as criticism, I was just curious if there was an optimisation reason; partly because I learned JS by accident, so the inner-workings remain something of a mystery.

Comment: I forgot to write this in the edit summary, but `String.prototype.contains` no longer exists. It’s been replaced by [`String.prototype.includes`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Answer (score 0):

I think for a given Array If it is an exact match. You can use `Array.includes`.

```js
const myArr = [ "blue", "red", "orange", "green" ];
console.log(myArr.includes("orange"))
```

If you are looking for just a fuzzy search you can use below codes.

```js
const myArr = ["blue", "red", "orange", "green"];

// Create a helper method, and look for contains/includes in each item
const contains = (arr = [], m) => arr.some((txt) => txt.includes(m));

console.log(contains(myArr, "orang"))


// This is fuzzy search. Check in whole array. join array in string and check for contains/includes
console.log(myArr.join("").includes("orang"));

// This is fuzzy search. Check in whole array. stringify array and check for contains/includes
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr).includes("orang"));
```

**Note:** Old browser may not support method `includes`. You can use index of instead

```
"test message".includes("test") /// true
//same as 
"test message".indexOf("test") !== -1 //true
```

Comment: `.join("")` and `JSON.stringify(...)` both work but have some false positives. When taking a look at the `.join("")` suggestion it would also return `true` for `"edor"`. `JSON.stringify(...)` has a similar problem where it returns `true` for `'ed","or'`. Only the last `.some(...)` option truly checks for substrings on each individual array element.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: Understood. I mentioned already for these are for fuzzy search. However, I updated in the comment. Thanks.