# How to check if a character is present in a string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**To keep it simple: I need to check that my string array has a given string or substring. It should return true if any element in the array has `+`**

I am trying to get a boolean value based on a character if present in a string array.
My Character is `+`
My string array is `["+23", "234", "32, "2323"]`
I tried using `includes, some`. But, it compares the whole string in the array element. Is there a way to check if the given string "+" just matches any element in string array.

```js
var arr = ['+22', '22',  '222', '21', '1', '12'];
var myString = "+";
var stringIncludes = arr.some(f=> myString.includes(f));
console.log(stringIncludes);
```

Here I am using the  `+` and it return false.

Comment: `myString.includes(fruit)` -> `fruit.includes(myString)` to check if `fruit` (the element from the array) has a given string `myString`. So, if `myString = "+"` you'd get `true`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if an array contains part of a string and the index #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554117/check-if-an-array-contains-part-of-a-string-and-the-index)

Comment: Why did you set `myString` to `I have an + and a watermelon.` and not just `+`?  Upon reading your question it seemed like you wanted to see if any of the strings in your array contained a `+`.  But I'm confused because it also now seems, just from the text of that string, that maybe you are trying to see if the string contains any of the substrings in your array...in which case,  your array does not contain a `'+'` string all by itself.  Can you clarify please?

Comment: Sorry, I did edit as per the comments. I just want to check if + is present in any element in the array either as a separate string or substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the roles of `f` and `myString`. The naming of your variables is possibly the source of the confusion, but `myString` is the *short* string, and `f` the potentially longer string. So you want to check whether `f` includes `myString` and not the other way round:

```js
var arr = ['+22', '22',  '222', '21', '1', '12'];
var myString = "+";
var stringIncludes = arr.some(f=> f.includes(myString));
console.log(stringIncludes);
```